# Android Emulator with ANGLE support

Tags: opengl-es, android-emulator

I heard that Almost Native Graphic Layer Engine (ANGLE) translates OpenGL commands to DirectX and provides better 3D performance on Windows system. How can I tell if my android emulator is using ANGLE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if d3d11.dll, d3d9.dll, D3DCompiler_47.dll are opened by your android emulator. As far as I know, LeapDroid and BlueStacks are the only two using ANGLE so far.

---

Links:
Leapdroid: http://www.leapdroid.com
BlueStacks: http://www.bluestacks.com